Navigation on Mars without Martian GPS
Given that the orbital period of Phobos and Deimos are different, and are relatively fast (7.66 hours, and 30.35 hours respectively) compared to our Moon, would future Scouts of Mars be able to easily calculate their location more easily than is done on Earth with tables, clock, and sextant?
If you have to wear a spacesuit to go outside, it is most likely that you've got the Martian equivalent of GPS, but just in the way people learn to navigate with sextants now, people might be interested in a 'back of the envelope' calculation for locating their position.

Note that Phobos orbits so close to the surface of Mars that it is not visible above about 70° Martian latitude north or south. As for Deimos, you must first identify it -- it is tiny and from the surface of Mars it looks like a bright star, sort of how Venus looks from Earth.

What are you actually asking?

The question revolves around knowing where you are on Mars, with a minimum of technology.   Because there are two moons, it might have been possible to know latitude (based on the Martian equivalent of Polaris, and that you can't see Phobos about 70 degrees as noted above), and perhaps something like the angle of the between the two in the sky, or the delta between the appearance of both above the horizon.   Because of the two relatively fast moving moons, it might be easier that terrestrial navigation techniques, but it appears from the answers, it is no.


would future Scouts of Mars be able to easily calculate their location more easily than is done on Earth with tables, clock, and sextant?

Assuming that one can see from the surface one or two of the satellites, one would still need to know

the time of the sol at which the observation is taking place (clock needed)
the position in the sky of the satellites (sextant needed)
determine where on the surface of Mars the above two pieces of information would be determined (tables needed)

Long story short: no, it cannot be done any easier than that.

worth noting you could combine all that in one instrument with todays electronics. It could even be all electronic, so the human has to do nothing more than point it at the sky.

I agree with @John that the process of keeping taking a measurement of different celestial objects off the horizon, taking a look at the time, and comparing that to charts and tables, could likely be very much automated.  I'd expect something like an iPhone could establish location in near real time by looking up at the sky and panning about a bit.  If somehow accurate time keeping is lost then there's ways to determine the time with some celestial observation, which can be complicated but still likely highly automated.  Whether this would be easier on Mars or Earth would likely be subjective.

In addition to L.Dutch's answer:
As well as clock, sextant and tables, I'd suggest a map.
Many aerial views have been accrued of the Red Planet, at different times of day with different shadow-lengths. The topography can be calculated from this leading to 3d maps on a tablet-like computer.
In any place on the surface, the view from the ground can be compared with the map (via camera) - the computer then compares the view with the model, giving a probability of  being at a certain latitude/longitude. At the very least they should have an interactive map of the terrain. The benefits are obvious.
Combined into a single instrument as per @John's comment, this would be powerful and compact.
The downside:
On flat plains (of which mars has a few), the horizon may not contain any identifying features, or not sufficient of them to identify location. It would be hit and miss at night as to how much it might help (clouds). It would require charging in order to function, solar is fine, but overuse might leave the equipment unusable 'till charged again. A single instrument doing everything is a single point of failure for the navigating capacity - unless they can make a makeshift sextant from "stuff" around.

Which has already been done on Mars, called terrain relative navigation, which is basically DSMAC developed for cruise missiles.

An electronic system that is critical to protecting human life such as navigation equipment would likely have a nuclear micro-battery in addition to solar PV for power. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery#Micro-batteries

Basic navigation skills would be important for survival for most any person in any situation but to rely on celestial navigation means one is thoroughly lost, as in lacking in any other markers in sight to determine location.
People navigating over the Great Plains would not be in need of celestial navigation because they would already have at least a general idea of where they are, and have maps and landmarks to guide them.  Take some group of "49ers" and plop them on some random part of Earth and they'd likely be quite lost for a very long time.  They didn't develop the skills for celestial navigation because the situation didn't call for it.
Scouts of Mars might want to teach celestial navigation because there may be a time in the future of any scout where they are in a spacecraft that makes an emergency landing on some random spot on Mars.  Then once they get an approximate idea on where they landed they'd turn to maps with landmarks and such to get an accurate fix.
Having a clock, sextant, and charts could mean navigation on Mars would be no more or less difficult than on Earth.  What might make navigation on Mars a bit more difficult is that there's no magnetic field on the planet that would allow for use of a compass.
Earth bound navigation equipment often have a barometric altimeter to give at least a general idea of altitude.  Such readings would give a very general idea of altitude unless calibrated against some fairly local reference to account for weather, if calibrated then accuracy improves considerably but I'm not sure how much.  Mars has a very thin atmosphere, and has weather, but I don't know if this means altitude can be accurately determined by barometric pressure to where it is helpful for finding a location on a topographical map.
I'm assuming the question is such that the scout has to navigate in a "power out" state, meaning no use of radio navigation or computers.  If that is the case then charts, sextant, a precision wind up mechanical timepiece, would likely allow a scout on Mars to get their navigation patch with similar difficulty as a scout on Earth.  The one factor that might add difficulty is the lack of a magnetic compass as one of the tools available.  Assuming an accurate clock is available and the sun is visible then the lack of a compass is likely a non-issue.
The scout can take a measurement of the position of the sun with a sextant, look at the time, compare that to the charts, and get a fairly accurate measure of latitude and longitude.  A measurement of a moon of Mars, and/or a measurement from a barometric altimeter, would presumably provide additional points of reference to narrow down position more accurately.  Once location is determined from celestial observations to get within a few miles of accuracy then the scout would likely switch to navigation by topographical maps and visible landmarks.
I believe basic land navigation is taught that one should take the proper measurements to determine location and then follow their compass to their destination.  Maybe a scout on Mars is allowed a bit of a "cheat" on this "lights out" kind of navigation and is permitted to have an electronic compass to stay on a straight path.  Keeping one eye on a clock and the other eye on position of the sun allows for a general idea of direction of travel but nighttime or dust clouds could obscure the sun and leave a scout guessing.

You would probably just use a map. Maybe beacons, too.
There are three complicating factors in marine navigation compared to land navigation:

when you are far away from shoreline, there are no features that would even hint about your position: it's water and water and water everywhere
winds and currents move your vessel in ways that you cannot keep track of in any reliable way without modern technology
beacons cannot be placed just anywhere, in fact most of marine surface is out of bounds.

Because of them, the ship's position would be more or less just an estimate that could be off even hundreds of kilometers/miles within few days.
The best solution they had was tables, clock and sextant. They were essential in marine navigation because using them you could estimate your position much more accurately. But, it was still an estimate. Those tools are not very accurate.
In Mars no such large bodies of water exist. It's all land there. And, on land, you can stay still if you want, and you can choose which way you move and how far, so you can keep track of your position without any issues. Around you, there are always some features (hills, big rocks, gorges etc.) that will be marked on the map, so you can definitely keep track of your location all the time. And, if you want to make it a bit easier, you can place beacons basically anywhere you need them.
Using a map will be more reliable and less hassle than tables, clock and sextant. If the map is accurate enough, you can pinpoint your location even down to some meters/yards, whereas a sextant only allows accuracy of several kilometers/miles.
A vast glacier might be the only place where this method can pose any issues, but that one is very easily solved with aforementioned beacons.

Before GPS US Navy managed to navigate submarines using radio telemetry network and inertial guidance. Along maps and geographic references.human civilization navigated EARTH without GPS for 6000 years, Mars has no Oceans thus no issue with featureless navigation.

" Mars has no Oceans thus no issue with featureless navigation. "  I'm pretty sure that Mars has large expanses of sand that will shift with the winds.  Give the sands a couple years to move and maps with sand dunes marked out will be useless.  Radio-navigation is a simple concept but people would still need training on the equipment.  Reading a map takes training too.  There could be a lot of hills that look like a lot of other hills so having some celestial navigation skills might be necessary to make sure the person is looking at the right page in their atlas.

Navigation is too important to have just one backup plan
Mars is not like Earth where you can just get lost in the wilderness and eventually find your way back to civilization.  The atmosphere is unbreathable; so, leaving your base is not something you just casually do on the day-to-day.  You have to plan out your trip exactly, and track your Oxygen requirements closely.  For things this important NASA typically plans 4-6 redundant systems; so, there is not going to just be 1 backup plan here.
A typical safety checklist for something like this should look like:

Ideally your GPS works without complication and your away mission is able to go according to plan.
If the GPS has a battery failure, you should have a backup battery or a way to let it draw power from another system. No space suit should be wholly reliant on a single power supply.
If your GPS has a mechanical/electrical failure, then your comms system will be able to triangulate the location of your base's radio tower. Abort mission and head straight home. Since your average radio tower is placed at least 150m above ground level, you should be able to use this from a minimum of 32km given the curvature of Mars. Modern EMU suits have enough oxygen to last 6.5-8hrs.  Decreased gravity and Martian off-road conditions will limit safe travel speeds to about 7 kph by rover or 4kph by foot limiting actual mission ranges to about 28km by rover or 16km by foot.  Actual missions will also have a safety margin; so, anything more than 10km will probably need to be done by drone anyway.  This means that you should never be able to go outside of radio range.
If all electrical systems fail and it is daytime, or your GPS failed and you do not have line of sight on the radio tower, then the astronaut will rely on thier knowledge of the maps of the area that they've studied to find thier way home via landmarks.  Again, these are trained astronauts going out on dangerous missions within 10km of thier base. They've probably logged hundreds of simulator hours traveling this area before they even left Earth; so, as long as they can see thier environment, they should always know where they are and how to get back safely.
If all electrical systems fail, and it is night time preventing you from seeing the landscape well enough to navigate by landmark, then the radio tower will have a blinking beacon light on it that you can visually see to guide you back home.  A 500 watt LED would appear about as bright as the 2rd brightest star from a max survivable range of 28km making it easy to spot as long as you don't have any hills get in the way.
If all electrical systems fail, if it is too dark to see the landscape, and the beacon light is not visible, use the stars as a compass.  At ranges of less than 28km, you don't need precise calculations to get back to somewhere you can see the beacon light.  The alignment of the stars will tell you about which way is North, and since you already know which approximate direction you came from you can mentally keep yourself moving the in right direction within about 10 degrees or so.  Just ballpark it in the right direction until you can spot the beacon light.

